# How to make dual screen crossover point upside

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, crossover

I have 2 monitors one above other, and the crossover point from one screen to other is from right side and I wanted to make it upside. Like, my pointer is currently in monitor1 (below) and I want to move to monitor2 (above), currently I have to move my mouse sideways to switch screens and I want to make my mouse move vertically to do the same action.

Comment: What operating system? If Windows, drag the monitors around in display settings.

Comment: I didn't know that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can drag the monitors around in "*Display Settings*" to arrange them as appropriate...

You can even offset them along an edge:

[image: Windows Display Settings]